# Recover the "original" order

Tags: sparql, wikidata-query-service

I am trying to recover the cast list for movies from wikidata.
My SPARQL query for Dr. No is as follows:

```
SELECT ?actor ?actorLabel WHERE {
  ?movie wdt:P161 ?actor .
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en". }
  FILTER(?movie = wd:Q102754)
}
LIMIT 1000
```

I can try it out at [query.wikidata.org](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20%3Factor%20%3FactorLabel%20WHERE%20%7B%0A%20%20%3Fmovie%20wdt%3AP161%20%3Factor%20.%0A%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22en%22.%20%7D%0A%20%20FILTER%28%3Fmovie%20%3D%20wd%3AQ102754%29%0A%7D%0ALIMIT%201000%0A) but the results are not in the order that I want. It gives 'Sean Connery', 'Zena Marshall', 'Ursula Andress'.

The database has the data in the required order as you can see from https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q102754 includes the cast list in order (Sean Connery, Ursula Andress, Joseph Wiseman). Generally the cast list is given in billing order and it is that that I want to recover.

Comment: The order in which statements are displayed on Wikidata is not carrying any semantic meaning and is just the chronological order they were added. So even if you figure something out that works for one movie, there is nothing that says that the actors were added similarly on another movie.

Answer (score 3):

SPARQL provides ordering of results by using `ORDER BY`, see [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#modOrderBy)

The ordering in your example is based on the number of references of a statement. Here is a non-optimized version that does what you want:

```sql
SELECT ?actor ?actorLabel WHERE {
  ?movie p:P161 ?statement .
  ?statement ps:P161 ?actor .
  OPTIONAL {?statement prov:wasDerivedFrom ?ref . }
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en". }
  FILTER(?movie = wd:Q102754)
}
group by ?movie ?actor ?actorLabel
ORDER BY DESC(count(?ref)) ASC(?actorLabel)
LIMIT 1000
```

Comment: Yes, that could get me the actors in alphabetic order - but I want them in order of importance - which is roughly the order they appear in the original data.

Comment: How to you know that the results are sorted by "importance"? What kind of measure is this?

Comment: Admittedly the "importance" is kind of vague - but in Wikipedia the actors are given (more or less) in the order that they appear in the movie credits. Generally the star of the movie comes first, the co-star comes second and so on down to "Man in a hurry at the station". My guess this is something that actors and agents care about a great deal. And it matters in application.

Comment: Ordering by the reference count is nice, and a good proxy in lots of cases. But it is not what I am after. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @SQLHacks It appears that on the page that you linked to in the question, they're ordered by reference. If that's not what you're looking for, then what *are* you looking for?  Generally, RDF triples don't impose an ordering on things.  Seeing three triples "x hasActor A . x hasActor B . x hasActor C" is the same as "x hasActor B . x hasActor C . x hasActor A".  Unless wikidata has some extra information, you'd have to define your own ordering.

Comment: I feared as much. Wikidata does have the sequence and I can get it from the json but that is a lot of work. Thanks for confirming that there is no ordering on the triples. (The first few cast members are ordered by reference count - but further down the list that's not true).

Comment: Then please ask on the Wikidata mailing **how** those things are ordered. Without, I can't give you the right SPARQL query. At least, there is no such measure like PageRank in the Wikidata endpoint.