# Sorting movie cast members by role relevancy

Tags: sorting, video, sparql, wikidata

I'm using the following query to retrieve all cast members for "Star Wars - The Force Awakens" using its IMDb identifier (`tt2488496`).

The problem is that the results are not sorted accordingly, for example, I would like to see some main characters like John Boyega, Adam Driver, Daisy Ridley, etc. appear on the top most section of the result, but the results just seem random.

For example, IMDb sorts by top-billed cast, and I don't know if wikidata has that kind of info, but if we look into the wikidata page for the Star Wars - The Force Awakens title (https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q6074), **in the cast member section**, you will see that they are sorted properly.

Is there any way to achieve the same sorting that wikidata has on [their title](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q6074) page?

**SPARQL query ([link](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20%3FtitleLabel%20%3FcastLabel%20%3FcastImdb%20WHERE%20%7B%0A%20%20VALUES%20%3FimdbIds%20%7B%20%22tt2488496%22%20%7D%0A%20%20%3Ftitle%20wdt%3AP345%20%3FimdbIds%20.%0A%20%20%3Fcast%20wdt%3AP345%20%3FcastImdb%20.%0A%20%20%23%20InstanceOf%20Film%0A%20%20%23%3Ftitle%20wdt%3AP31%20wd%3AQ11424%20%0A%20%20%3Ftitle%20wdt%3AP161%20%3Fcast%20.%0A%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22en%22%20.%0A%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%7D%0A%23ORDER%20BY%20%3FcastImdb%0A)):**

```
SELECT ?titleLabel ?castLabel ?castImdb WHERE {
  VALUES ?imdbIds { "tt2488496" }
  ?title wdt:P345 ?imdbIds .
  ?cast wdt:P345 ?castImdb .
  ?title wdt:P161 ?cast .
  SERVICE wikibase:label {
    bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en" .
   }
 }
```

Comment: Is it some university assignment? The same question was asked before here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42387768/recover-the-original-order

Comment: It is not a university assignment. It is for a personal project. But I did not knew that there was already a question. Thanks for pointing that out :)

Comment: No problem, I was just wondering why there was a very similar question some time ago. Unfortunately, last time we couldn't answer the question correctly, but we asked him to ask for clarification on the Wikidata mailing list.

Comment: Any chance I could get an answer similar to the one you posted on the other [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42387768/recover-the-original-order), but with IMDb identifiers, like the ones on my query?